# Google Actions keeps loading the same response even though the response should be random via the API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, webhooks

I'm am currently trying to create a simple Google Action that says the title and summary of a random wikipedia article. I'm using this API here: https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary

I have the action to only load the webhook and nothing else.

Here's the webhook:

Index.js

```
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request');
const app = conversation();

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary';

request(url, (error, response, body)=>{
    app.handle('wiki_random', conv => {
    dataObj = JSON.parse(body);
    title = dataObj.title;
    summary = dataObj.extract;
    speech = `${title}... ${summary}`;
    conv.add(speech);
    });
});
exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Actions on Google fulfillment",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "@assistant/conversation": "^3.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.2"
    
  }
  
}
```

When going to test the action it keeps loading the same article as if it isn't actually loading the API correctly. Is there anything in my code that would enable this type of behavior?

When doing this in a node.js console it loads a random article perfectly fine each time. Never any duplicates.

Comment: Unrelated, but consider using sensible indentation when writing code - it makes things much easier to debug when you can see the blocks at a glance

Comment: @CertainPerformance Noted. Thanks for the tip. Makes sense.